# simple keras nn does not predict well

Tags: neural-network, keras

the code:

```
x1 = np.array([1, 10])
x2 = np.array([7, 4])
x3 = np.array([8, 7])
x4 = np.array([1, 15])
x5 = np.array([4, 4])
X = np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4, x5])
X = X / 100
Y = np.array([4, 8, 7, 5, 1])
Y = Y / 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, batch_size=3)
toPred = np.array([x1]) / 100
print(model.predict(toPred) * 100)
```

For everything I predict I get a strange result, all the predictions are almost the same and are not close to the real value.

Suggestions?

Comment: What is your data? An what are you predicting

Comment: This is a very artificial data, as I inserted in the code itself.
X is attributes vector for each record, and Y is the result. 
i'm expecting to get Y from X again, but I get something completely wrong.

Comment: why is the output wrong? can you post a sample of that too?

Comment: This is what I get from x1 to x5:

[[ 7.03928041]] y1
[[ 7.04014397]] y2
[[ 7.03316259]] y3
[[ 7.03048801]] y4
[[ 7.04527283]] y5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample instead, I didn't change much just a different approach to scaling, and a longer training time.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


x1 = np.array([1, 10])
x2 = np.array([7, 4])
x3 = np.array([8, 7])
x4 = np.array([1, 15])
x5 = np.array([4, 4])
X = np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4, x5])

# Scale to range 0-1 since input activation is a sigmoid
X = (X - X.std()) / X.mean()

#Dont need to scale Y, leaves us with one less unnecessary operation
Y = np.array([4, 8, 7, 5, 1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="uniform"))

#Set output activation to linear
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

#Train for 5k epochs, since the loss keeps decreasing
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=5000, batch_size=5)

print(model.predict(X))
```

gives me

```
[[ 3.50988507]
 [ 7.0278182 ]
 [ 7.61787605]
 [ 5.38016272]
 [ 1.63140726]]
```

Sometimes you just need to tinker with the hyper-parameters. You could probably eliminate the second dense layer since this data is small and I also get better results using the `'SGD'` (stochastic gradient descent) optimizer. You can also get good results faster by turning up the learning rate (may only work well for this snippet). So just play around until you get result your looking for. Hope this helps :)

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
opt = SGD(lr=.05)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, batch_size=5)
```